# What could be the formula to get centavos or 2 decimal places?

Tags: c

I'm doing a program that would input the weekly pay and total hours worked in that week. And it should display the answer in hourly pay rate. But I can't display the correct "centavos/2 decimal places" formula and it doesn't want to run with float % float. Please help!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int gethourpaypes(int weekpay, int hoursworked)
{
  int hourpaypes;
  hourpaypes = weekpay / hoursworked;
  return hourpaypes;
}

int gethourpaycent(int weekpay, int hoursworked)
{
  int hourpaycent;
  hourpaycent = ((weekpay / hoursworked) % 100);
  return hourpaycent;
}

int main()
{
  int hourpaypes, weekpay, hoursworked;
  int hourpaycent;
  printf("Enter total week pay in pesos: ");
  scanf("%d", &weekpay);
  printf("Enter total hours worked that week: ");
  scanf("%d", &hoursworked);
  hourpaypes = gethourpaypes(weekpay, hoursworked);
  hourpaycent = gethourpaycent(weekpay, hoursworked);
  printf("Your hourly pay rate is %.0d pesos and %.2d centavos", hourpaypes, hourpaycent);
  fflush(stdin);
  getchar();
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior  http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `fmod` to compute a floating point remainder. `%` operator can only be used with operands of integer types.

```
#include <math.h>
double fmod(double x, double y);
float fmodf(float x, float y);
```

Comment: Is there any other way? I have to code this using Basic C language. Thank you! @ouah

Comment: `fmod` is a standard C function.

Comment: @TrollerKid The `<math.h>` header file and all its functions are part of the core C standard.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Alright, but would there be any other way to use unary operators? Or is that only way to do it? (This code is open for changes like the data types) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid both your calculations are incorrect. The pesos calculation actually calculates the hourly pay, and you only *seem* to get integer pesos because you print it with no decimals.

The hourly pay is

```
hourpay = weekpay / hoursworked;
```

From that, you get hourly pay in pesos with `floor()` to obtain an integer (not an `int`) number:

```
pesos = floor(hourpay);
```

and centavos as remainder; this is usually done with `round()`, so that 12.345 becomes 12 pesos and 35 centavos (but you can truncate it with `floor()` instead of `round()`):

```
cvos  = round(100.0*(hourpay - pesos));
```

**INTEGER ARITHMETIC**

You convert the week pay to centavos, then divide by the hours worked. To keep rounding errors to a minimum, you leave everything in `float` until the last moment.

```
int main()
{
    float weekpay, hoursworked;
    int centavos_per_hour, psos, cvos;

    printf("Enter total week pay in pesos: ");
    scanf("%f", &weekpay);
    printf("Enter total hours worked that week: ");
    scanf("%f", &hoursworked);

    centavos_per_hour = (weekpay * 100.0) / hoursworked;

    psos = centavos_per_hour / 100;  // Hourly pay is 2345 co = 23 pesos
    cvos = centavos_per_hour % 100;  // 

    printf("Your hourly pay is %d pesos %d centavos per hour\n", psos, cvos);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Iserni Is there an alternative way? With just using the unary operators? Thank you!

Comment: Well, your best option would be to ditch `floats` altogether and use integer arithmetic. I'm editing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create problems for yourself and others, don't use float/double/etc to represent money. Use integers, where 1 is the smallest unit of money, cent(avo) in your case.